# AngularJs: Can't set option as selected in select programatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

I have a service that calls to pop up.
The pop up is contains two drop-down lists.
The user is asked to choose the two drop down lists and press ok to return to the service.

In the next call to the pop up i would like that the pop up will display the previous options that was selected by the user.

Everytime i returns to the pop up the drop down are full but no selection has happened and i can't figure out what i am missing.

The service that calls to the pop up:

```
app.service('OriginalService', [ '$modal',

function ($modal) {
    var that = this;

    this.filtersMananger = { // my-ng-models for the two drop-down-lists
        firstFilter: "",
        secondFilter: ""
    };

    this.openDialog = function(){
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'ModalScreen.html',
            controller: 'ModalController',
            resolve: {
                filtersManagerObject: function () {
                    return that.filtersMananger;
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (filtersMananger) {
            that.filtersMananger.firstFilter = filtersMananger.selectedFirstFilter;
            that.filtersMananger.secondFilter = filtersMananger.selectedSecondFilter;
        }, function () {

        });
    };
}
]);
```

The pop up html:

```
<div class="data-filters-container">
     <div class="data-filter">
        <label for="filter-data-drop-down">FIRST FILTER</label>
        <select name="filterDataDropDown" ng-model="filtersMananger.selectedFirstFilter" ng-options="filter.value as filter.name for filter in filterDropDownItems"></select>
    </div>
      <div class="data-filter col-xs-4">
        <label for="filter-data-drop-down">SECOND FILTER</label>
        <select name="filterDataDropDown" ng-model="filtersMananger.selectedSecondFilter" ng-options="filter.value as filter.name for filter in filterDropDownItems"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code :

```
app.controller('ModalController', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'filtersManagerObject',
                                     function ($scope, $modalInstance, filtersManagerObject) {

    $scope.filtersMananger = {
        selectedFirstFilter : "",
        selectedSecondFilter : ""
    };

    $scope.filterDropDownItems = [

        {name: "4h", value: "lastFourHours"},
        {name: "24h", value: "lastDay"},
        {name: "All", value: "all"}
    ];                                                                              

    /*
    * The function checks if the the values in filters are not "".
    * If there are not so we found the selected filter and returns it.
    */
    $scope.fillPreviousSelections = function(){
        if ($scope.isfiltersManagerObjectNotEmpty()){
            $scope.fillSelections();
        }
    };

    $scope.isfiltersManagerObjectNotEmpty = function(){
        return (filtersManagerObject.firstFilter !== "" || filtersManagerObject.secondFilter !== "");
    };

    $scope.fillSelections = function(){
        if (filtersManagerObject.firstFilter !== ""){
            $scope.findDropDownItem(filtersManagerObject.firstFilter);
        }
    };

    $scope.findDropDownItem = function(filterValue){
        var isFound = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filterDropDownItems.length && !isFound; i++){
            var dropDownItem = $scope.filterDropDownItems[i];
            if (dropDownItem.value === filterValue){
               //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
               Maybe the problem is here:
                $scope.filtersMananger.selectedOneFilter = dropDownItem;

                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                isFound = true;
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.fillPreviousSelections();

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.filtersMananger);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem :)

Look at the select tag:

```
<select name="filterDataDropDown" ng-model="filtersMananger.selectedFirstFilter" ng-options="filter.value as filter.name for filter in filterDropDownItems"></select>
```

The ng-model in this case (filtersMananger.selectedFirstFilter) holds the value (filter.value).

So in my function in which i search the proper item from the drop down list named

```
$scope.findDropDownItem
```

I need to return the value of the item and not the item itself.

```
 $scope.findDropDownItem = function(filterValue){
        var isFound = false;
        var dropDownItemToReturn = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filterDropDownItems.length && !isFound; i++){
            var dropDownItem = $scope.filterDropDownItems[i];
            if (dropDownItem.value === filterValue){
                dropDownItemToReturn = dropDownItem;
                isFound = true;
            }
        }
       //my change:
        return dropDownItemToReturn.value;
    };
```

After that i assigned the returned value to the model:

```
var previousDropDownItem =  $scope.findDropDownItem(filtersManagerObject.oneFilterFilter);
$scope.filtersMananger.selectedOneFilter = previousDropDownItem ;
```

And that it!! :)